# Place an order in tradingview based on an indicator

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Is it possible to create a script in tradingview that opens and closes orders based on an indicator? I have an indicator that gives me buy and sell signals and is very accurate. I want to use those signals to open buy and sell orders in tradingview connected to forex.com.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that automatically with Tradingview yet.

You need a 3rd party application. So, you would trigger some alerts and use web-hooks to coneect to this 3rd party application. Then it would receive your commands and forward it to your exchange/broker.